# VBA script for automating excel, click 'ok' on dialog box

Tags: excel, vbscript, msgbox

I (as a non developer) am trying to create a VB script to:

open an excel spreadsheet (one that I didn't create), 
add values to fields, 
click on a 'validate' button which checks the format of these fields against pre-defined rules, 
save and close the spreadsheet.

The bit that I am getting stuck on is the dialog box that appears when I click the validate button. I just need to click on an 'ok' button, or ignore the dialog box all together.

I've looked at various things including SendKeys and DisplayAlerts = False but neither seem to work.

My code is as below:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

objExcel.Visible=True

Set objWorkbook=objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\TestSpreadsheet.xls")
Set objWorksheet=objWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

objExcel.Application.Visible=True
objExcel.WorkSheets(2).Activate



' objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.WorkSheets(2).Unprotect
objExcel.WorkSheets(2).Cells(3,1).Value="Test1"
objExcel.WorkSheets(2).Cells(3,2).Value="Test1"

' Click 'validate' button.
objWorksheet.CommandButton2.Value = True

'Click 'ok'

??????


' Save the spreadsheet and close the workbook.
' Specify Excel7 File Format.
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close


' Quit Excel.
objExcel.Application.Quit

Wscript.Echo "Done"
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than clicking the button so to speak, you need to fire the event that the button does when clicked.  Usually this is the Click event.

Try:

```
objWorksheet.CommandButton2_Click()
```

To fire the click event.  If that fails, you can always just directly run the macros or code that the button does by examining the event.